# Comparing nonlinear regression models

Tags: r, nls

I want to compare the curve fits of three models by r-squared values. I ran models using the `nls` and `drc` packages. It appears, though, that neither of those packages calculate r-squared values; they give "residual std error" and "residual sum of squares" though.

Can these two be used to compare model fits?

Comment: You shouldn't use r-squared to compare models. In fact, I'm a bit skeptical why you'd want to compare different nonlinear models. Model selection for non-linear modeling is best base on the science of the problem.

Comment: @Roland I am comparing two growth models for an algal specie. So I wanted to see which one explains the growth data (generated from lab experiments) better. Excuse me for not clearly explaining the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is really a statistics question, rather than a coding question: consider posting on [stats.stackexchange.com](https://stats.stackexchange.com/); you're likely to get a better answer.

RSQ is not really meaningful for non-linear regression. This is why `summary.nls(...)` does not provide it. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530770/calculating-r2-for-a-nonlinear-model) for an explanation.

There is a common, and understandable, tendency to hope for a single statistic that allows one to assess which of a set of models better fits a dataset. Unfortunately, it doesn't work that way. Here are some things to consider.

1. Generally, the best model is the one that has a mechanistic underpinning. Do your models reflect some physical process, or are you just trying a bunch of mathematical equations and hoping for the best? The former approach almost always leads to better models.
2. You should consider how the models will be used. Will you be interpolating (e.g. estimating y|x within the range of your dataset), or will you be extrapolating (estimating y|x outside the range of your data)? Some models yield a fit that provides relatively accurate estimates slightly outside the dataset range, and others completely fall apart.
3. Sometimes the appropriate modeling technique is suggested by the type of data you have. For example, if you have data that counts something, then y is likely to be poisson distributed and a generalized linear model (glm) in the poisson family is indicated. If your data is binary (e.g. only two possible outcomes, success or failure), then a binomial glm is indicated (so-called logistic regression).
4. The key underlying assumption of least squares techniques is that the error in y is normally distributed with mean 0 and constant variance. We can test this after doing the fit by looking at a plot of standardized residuals vs. y, and by looking at a Normal Q-Q plot of the residuals. If the residuals plot shows scatter increasing or decreasing with y then the model in not a good one. If the Normal Q-Q plot is not close to a straight line, then the residuals are not normally distributed and probably a different model is indicated.
5. Sometimes certain data points have high leverage with a given model, meaning that the fit is unduly influenced by those points. If this is a problem you will see it in a leverage plot. This indicates a weak model.
6. For a given model, it may be the case that not all of the parameters are significantly different from 0 (e.g., p-value of the coefficient > 0.05). If this is the case, you need to explore the model without those parameters. With nls, this often implies a completely different model.
7. Assuming that your model passes the tests above, it is reasonable to look at the F-statistic for the fit. This is essentially the ratio of SSR/SSE corrected for the dof in the regression (R) and the residuals (E). A model with more parameters will generally have smaller residual SS, but that does not make it a better model. The F-statistic accounts for this in that models with more parameters will have larger regression dof and smaller residual dof, making the F-statistic smaller.
8. Finally, having considered the items above, you can consider the residual standard error. Generally, *all other things being equal*, smaller residual standard error is better. Trouble is, all other things are *never* equal. This is why I would recommend looking at RSE last.

Comment: Thanks @jlhoward for the detailed reply. It is really helpful. Regarding the models, yes, they do explain physical process. I am  studying algal growth kinetics. I just wanted to compare two growth models and see which one fits the experimental data better and hence will predict the growth better in a water body. 
Thanks again!